# To set CommandTarget of WPF control as Textbox which is written in Win form user Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i want to set the **CommandTarget** property of menu item to the TextControl which is written in win form 
or just tell me any way which can execute the command lets say cut copy paste on the control which is written in win form user control and added to xaml through **WindowsFormsHost**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set WPF properties on WinForms objects.
You have to hook the events on WinForms controls the WinForms way.